# OpenLayers: Export from / Import to KML - keeping the layer structure

Tags: openlayers-2, geojson, export, kml, import

I have following structure before export:

- LayerGroup

  - LayerGroup

    - Layer

      - Feature

Is there any posibility to keep this structure when export/import KML?

I noticed in the KML file after I export feature, open layers creates folder tags. I wonder if those folder tags could be mapped to the Layers or LayerGroup. I would also consider a solution that includes GeoJSON instead of KML file.

Answer (score 0):

You can do multi-level nesting with Folders in KML (folders can contain sub-folders), so it should be possible to keep your structure in KML.  Google Earth and many other KML renderers will render that structure, but note that some KML renderers may flatten the folder structure.

Comment: Thank you for your hint. After some research it looks like open layers doesn't not support such a render and one should implement its own way of doing it for both writing & reading.